# Advantages to different ways of declaring a variable in c++ when using .size()?

Tags: c++, initialization

Consider the code below:

```
//ask for user's name
cout << "What is your FIRST name?\n\n";

//read the user's name
string name; //define name
cin >> name; //read into name

//build the message we want to write
const string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
```

Suppose I want to know the number of characters in the string variable `greeting`. A simple way to do this is with `.size()`. Suppose I want to call the resulting value `greetingLength`

Is there any benefit to writing

```
const int greetingLength(greeting.size());
```

instead of

```
const int greetingLength=greeting.size();
```

This question probably has a very obvious question, but I'm a total noob to c++. I've been using MATLAB for over a decade, so the second option looks much better to me, but many tutorials seem to have preference for the first option.

Comment: The two are equivalent in effect.   The bigger concern is that a `std::string`s `size()` member does not return an `int` - it returns an implementation-defined UNSIGNED type - which can result in surprises on conversion and subsequent usage.\

Comment: Thanks, Peter. That explains the warning that Xcode was throwing at me! Like I said, I'm very new to thing, so the help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This form:

```
const int greetingLength(greeting.size());
```

is [direct-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)

> initialization with a nonempty parenthesized list of expressions or braced-init-lists

and the effect is:

> Otherwise, standard conversions are used, if necessary, to convert the value of other to the cv-unqualified version of T, and the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value.

---

This form:

```
const int greetingLength=greeting.size();
```

is [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

> when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) of a non-reference type T is declared with the initializer consisting of an equals sign followed by an expression.

and the effect is:

> Otherwise (if neither T nor the type of other are class types), standard conversions are used, if necessary, to convert the value of other to the cv-unqualified version of T.

---

So both forms have the effect of using standard conversions to convert `greeting.size()` to an `int` and initializing `greetingLength`, and are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the link:

```cpp
  int a=5;               // initial value: 5
  int b(3);              // initial value: 3
  int c{2};              // initial value: 2
```

All of these statements are valid and equivalent.
ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/